# While executing a runnable jar file(java code), I am getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, excel, executable-jar, runnable, read-write

As part of one of my project tasks, I need to read some data from excel, work on an application using this data through Sikuli, and then write the result back to Excel.

It's working fine in Eclipse. But when I export the Java file to a Runnable jar file, I get an error (the stack trace is at the bottom of this post). Can anyone help me fix this?

Please find below my Java code:

```html
package Auto_a;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Key;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class Calculator_b {

 public static String[] temp1 = new String[50];
 public static String temp,temp2;
 public static String var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12;
 public static String var13,var14,var15,var16,var17,var18,var19,var20;
 public static String str5;
 public static String result,result_a,result_b;
 public static String[] temp_var;
 public static String result1,result2;
 public static int rowNum,colNum;
 public static String[] temp_var2 ;
 public static int x=0,flag=0;
 public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException, InterruptedException, FindFailed
    {    
  
   Screen s=new Screen();   
   Thread.sleep(2000); 
   
   s.find("D:\\Sikuli\\Calculator.PNG");    
   Thread.sleep(500);
   s.click("D:\\Sikuli\\Calculator.PNG");   
   Thread.sleep(2000);  
   
   Calculator_b objExcelFile = new Calculator_b();       

   String filePath = "D:";
   //Call read file method of the class to read data       
   objExcelFile.readExcel(filePath,"sample.xlsx","Calculator");
   
    }
 
 
 public void readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName) throws IOException, FindFailed, InterruptedException
 {       

  //Create a object of File class to open xlsx file       
  File file =    new File(filePath+"\\"+fileName);       
  //Create an object of FileInputStream class to read excel file      
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
  
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  
  //Read sheet inside the workbook by its name       
  //Sheet guru99Sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);   
  
     XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

     rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
     System.out.println(rowNum);
     colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
     System.out.println(colNum);
     String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
     temp_var2 = new String[colNum+1];

     for (int i = 1 ; i < rowNum ; i++) 
     { 
         XSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
             for (int j = 1 ; j < colNum ; j++) 
             {
                 XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                 String value = cellToString(cell);
                
                 data[i][j] = value ;                 
             }                           
          
      }
     
     //New Loop to assign data to Temp array
     
     for(int i1=1;i1 < rowNum ; i1++)
     {      
      for (int j1 = 1 ; j1 < colNum ; j1++) 
            {
       x=j1;
       temp_var2[x]=data[i1][j1];          
       System.out.println("value of temp_var2["+x +"]: "+ temp_var2[x]);
       x=x+1;
            }
      Calculator_a(i1);      
     }     
  
     int len111 = temp_var2.length;
     System.out.println("array len: "+len111); 
      
 }     
 
  public static String cellToString(XSSFCell cell) 
     {  
         int type;
         Object result;
         type = cell.getCellType();

         switch (type) 
         {

             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // numeric value in Excel
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: // precomputed value based on formula
                 result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                 break;
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // String Value in Excel 
                 result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                 break;
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                 result = "";
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: //boolean value 
                 result = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                 break;
             case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
             default:  
                 throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of cell");                        
         }

         return result.toString();
     }
  
  public static void WriteExcel(int var_c,String str1,String Result) 
     { 
   int var_d =var_c;
   String Actual = str1;
   String status = Result;
   try {
       FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\sample_h.xlsx"));
    
       XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
       XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Calculator");
       Cell cell = null;
    
       //Update the value of cell
       cell = sheet.getRow(var_d).getCell(5);      
       cell.setCellValue(Actual);
       
       cell = sheet.getRow(var_d).getCell(6);      
       cell.setCellValue(status);       

      //file.close();
        
       FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\sample_h.xlsx"));
       workbook.write(outFile);
       //outFile.close();
        
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  
  public static void Calculator_a(int v_a)throws FindFailed, InterruptedException 
  {
   int v_b=v_a;    
  
    Screen s=new Screen();   
    Thread.sleep(2000);    
        
    s.find("D:\\Sikuli\\Calculator_c.PNG");    
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s.click("D:\\Sikuli\\Calculator_c.PNG");     
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    s.type(temp_var2[1]);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
 
    s.type(temp_var2[3]);    
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    s.type(temp_var2[2]);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    s.type(Key.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    String text1;
    text1=s.find("D:\\Sikuli\\Calculator_b.PNG").above(30).text();
    text1=text1.trim();
    System.out.println("Actual Result: "+text1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String expected = temp_var2[4];
    if(expected.equals(text1))
    {
     result1="Passed";
     WriteExcel(v_b,text1,result1);     
    }
    
    else
    {
     result1="Failed";
     WriteExcel(v_b,text1,result1);      
    }
          
  }
 }
```

```html
Error details:

*****sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, 'D:\testa.jar'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sikuli****

at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:46)
        at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:43)
        at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:61)
        at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:290)
        at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:750)
        at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:834)
        at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:884)
        at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
        at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
        at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:978)
        at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:954)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(<string>:1)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(<string>)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1261)
        at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1305)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:206)
        at org.sikuli.script.Region.toJythonRegion(Region.java:993)
        at org.sikuli.script.Region.create(Region.java:130)
        at org.sikuli.script.Region.above(Region.java:331)
        at Auto_a.Calculator_b.Calculator_a(Calculator_b.java:192)
        at Auto_a.Calculator_b.readExcel(Calculator_b.java:98)
        at Auto_a.Calculator_b.main(Calculator_b.java:47)
        ... 5 more
```

I feel that issue is occurring while writing the data to Excel / reading the data from Excel. Could you please suggest any solution?

I've exported the java code to a jar file in the correct manner. I've confirmed this by exporting another sample program, and it worked perfectly. This problem only occurs in a program which involves Excel Read & Excel Write operations

Comment: I ran the jar file (which has the above code) in Command prompt. Please find below the complete o/p:                                            D:\>java -jar testa.jar
[info] Windows utilities loaded.
[info] Sikuli vision engine loaded.
[log] CLICK on (771,747)
[log] CLICK on (209,16)
[log] TYPE "24"
[log] TYPE "+"
[log] TYPE "20"
[log] TYPE "
"
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, 'D:\testa.jar'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
followed by the error mentioned above

Comment: ExcelData                                                                                                 S.No  Num1  Num2 Operator ExpectedResult  ActualResult Status
1        24      20    +    44  
2        24      20    -     4  
3        24      2    *    48  
4        24      2    /    12

Comment: Hi All,  Can anyone please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sikuli****
```

It seems to fail to import sikuli.